# Non standard primary keys in Rails test databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In one of my models I use a non standard primary which is handled in the migration file like this:

```
create_table item_similarities, :id => false do |t|
```

and

```
execute "ALTER TABLE item_similarities ADD constraint pk_item_similarities " +
        "PRIMARY KEY (item_id_1, item_id_2)"
```

Now, when I run `rake test` the schema is copied into the test database but without setting the primary key (item_id_1, item_id_2) in the test database.

Could anyone please help how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails dumps it schema information into db/schema.rb. Check that file, but your own SQL will probably not be there. You can set it to dump sql, but I don't know if your own SQL will be included:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format = :sql
```

Comment: Yes, it included my own SQL! Now, when running "rake test" structure of the development database is dumped in db/development_structure.sql. This file is used to recreate the test database which now exactly matches the development database.

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't have a lot of support for composite primary keys.

Try dumping the sql structure of your database like this:

```
rake db:structure:dump
```

It should create a file like db/development_structure.sql

Then do this to load that file into your test database:

```
rake db:test:clone_structure
```